# check the checkbox if visible

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes and i have a select_all checkbox. Please check the comment in the code.

```
$('#select_all').change(function() {        
    var checkboxes = $("input[name^='select']");
    if($('#select_all').is(':checked')) {
           //here i want to check where this checkbox (checkbox from the list not select_all checkbox) is visible or not.
           // if visible then check the checkbox
        checkboxes.attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        checkboxes.removeAttr('checked');
    }
});
```

Is there any think like this to check the visibility:--

```
  $("input[name^='select'][checked]").each(   
         function() {   
                // Insert code here   
             }   
  );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [:visible selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

```
$('#select_all').change(function() {        
    var checkboxes = $("input[name^='select']");

    if (this.checked) {
        checkboxes.filter(':visible').attr('checked', true);
    } else {
        checkboxes.attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Note how I've used the correct method of setting the `checked` attribute; the value should be a boolean, not a string.

Comment: @Matt no i want to check the element from the list is visible or not. In ur code you are checking is visible or not. U getting what i m trying to say. I m really sry for not explaining in proper way.

Comment: @Matt We can use if($('#select_all').is(':checked'))  instead of using length. Is it fine ?

Comment: @piemesons: You can if you want. There's no difference unless you want to save 0.000000001ms; in which case my code will be quicker.

Comment: There's no need to use a function call at all in the `if($('#select_all:checked').length)` bit. Just do this: `if(this.checked)`. Within the handler `this` is the DOM element in question, and its checked state is reflected in the `checked` property: http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-30233917

Comment: @T.JCrowder: Good point... maybe 8:30am was too early to be answering questions on S.O :P

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
$('#select_all').change(function() {
    // Is "select all" checked?
    if(this.checked) {
        // Yes, check all *visible* checkboxes
        $("input[name^='select']:visible").attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        // No, uncheck all checkboxes (visible or not)
        $("input[name^='select']").removeAttr('checked');
    }
});
```

...but I'd also be a bit more cautious and put a `[type=checkbox]` in the selector:

```
$('#select_all').change(function() {
    // Is "select all" checked?
    if(this.checked) {
        // Yes, check all *visible* checkboxes
        $("input[name^='select'][type=checkbox]:visible").attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        // No, uncheck all checkboxes (visible or not)
        $("input[name^='select'][type=checkbox]").removeAttr('checked');
    }
});
```

Separately, for me it's always a red flag if the action of something is unbalanced — in this case, checking the "select all" will check all the visible ones, but unchecking it will uncheck *all* of them. I'd probably either do this:

```
$('#select_all').change(function() {
    var checkboxes = $("input[name^='select'][type=checkbox]:visible");
    // Is "select all" checked?
    if(this.checked) {
        // Yes, check all *visible* checkboxes
        checkboxes.attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        // No, uncheck all *visible* checkboxes
        checkboxes.removeAttr('checked');
    }
});
```

...or this:

```
$('#select_all').change(function() {
    // Is "select all" checked?
    if(this.checked) {
        // Yes, check all *visible* checkboxes...
        $("input[name^='select']:visible").attr('checked', 'checked');

        // ...and make sure all the invisible ones are unchecked
        $("input[name^='select'][type=checkbox]:not(:visible)").removeAttr('checked');
    } else {
        // No, uncheck all checkboxes (visible or not)
        $("input[name^='select'][type=checkbox]").removeAttr('checked');
    }
});
```

...but you know your requirements better than I do.